# How to get high availability when download data on 2 servers?

Tags: networking, server, architecture, software-design

I have data need to be downloaded on a local server every 24 hours. For high availability we provided 2 servers to avoid failures and losing data.

My question is: What is the best approach to use the 2 servers?

My ideas are:

-Download on a server and just if download failed for any reason, download will continue on the other server.

-Download will occur on the 2 servers at the same time every day.

Any advice?

Comment: Is the software responsible for executing the download located on these servers?  If not, where?  How critical is the time of download?  Are the two servers located in different locations?  Is this an existing solution?

Comment: When you say "for high availability" do you mean guaranteed download of the data, or, that the downloaded data is highly available?  Or both?

Comment: @AdrianK 
The software responsible for executing the download will be located on these servers.

Download will occur daily at 02:00 am.

The two servers located in different locations.

The solution is existing and it's another required to download data from cloud and save it on premise.

When you say "for high availability" do you mean guaranteed download of the data, or, that the downloaded data is highly available? Or both?

Hight availability here means both of guaranteed download of the data and the downloaded data is highly available.

Comment: How will the data be consumed once it has been downloaded?  e.g. will users be accessing it through a website, direct download, or is it to be consumed by an automated system/integration?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your high-level approach, break it down into manageable chunks i.e. reliable data acquisition, and highly available data dissemination.  I would start with the second part first, because that's the state you want to get to.

**Highly available data dissemination**

Working backwards (i.e. this is the second part of your problem), when offering highly-available data to consumers you have two options:

1. Active-Passive
2. Active-Active

Active-Active means you have at least two nodes servicing requests for the data, with some kind of Load Balancer (LB) in front, which allocates the requests.  Depending on the technology you are using there may be existing components/solutions in that tech stack, or reference models describing potential solutions.

Active-Passive means you have one node taking all the traffic, and when that becomes unavailable requests are directed at the stand-by / passive node.

The passive node can be "hot" ready to go, or "cold" - meaning it's not fully operational but is relatively fast and easy to stand-up and start taking traffic.

In both cases, and if you have only 2 nodes, you ideally want both the nodes to be capable of handling the entire load.  That's obvious for Active-Passive, but it also applies to active-active, so that if one goes down the other will successfully handle all requests.

In both cases you need some kind of network component that routes the traffic.  Ideally it will be able to operate autonomously (it will have to if you want active-active load sharing), but you could have a manual / alert based process for switching from active to passive.  For one thing, it will depend on what your non-functional requirements are.

**Reliable data acquisition**

Having figured out how you will disseminate the data, you know where you need to get it to.

E.g. **if active-active** you need to get it to both at the same time (I don't know what tolerances you can have) since you want them to serve the same consistent data.  One option to get around that issues is this:

- Have the LB route all traffic to node A.
- Node B performs the download.
- The LB is informed that Node B successfully got the new data and is ready to serve it.  LB then switches the traffic flow to just Node B.
- Node A gets the updated data (perhaps from Node B, so the data is guaranteed to be the same).
- The LB is informed that Node A successfully got the new data and is ready to serve it.  LB then allows the traffic flow to Nodes A & B.

This pattern would also work for **active-passive**:

- Node A is the active node, B is the passive node.
- Node B downloads the new data, and is ready to serve it.
- Node A gets updated with the new data (probably from node B), to ensure consistency.
- Node A serves the new data.

You get the data on the passive node first so that if node A went down, node B would already have the new data.  Admittedly the time-window for that to happen should be quite small.